# How to copy a boost::numeric::ublas::vector to a matrix?

Tags: c++, boost, vector, matrix, ublas

What am I doing wrong here?

```
// file main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_proxy.hpp>

namespace ublas = boost::numeric::ublas;

int main()
{
    ublas::vector<double> const v( 10 );
    ublas::matrix<double> m( 1, v.size() );
    ublas::matrix_row<ublas::matrix<double> > r( m, 1 );
    r = v;
    return 0;
}
```

This fails with message:

```
Check failed in file /usr/local/include/boost/numeric/ublas/functional.hpp at line 1370:
i < size_i
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::numeric::ublas::bad_index'
  what():  bad index
Aborted
```

However, is there more laconic way to `v` into `m` at `main.cpp`?

Comment: Nothing wrong with iterating; but I am using boost, so I am hoping to get rid of tedious stuff like that.

Comment: Fair enough. I worked quite a bit with boost ublas in my last semester at school, and don't recall any easy function to do what you're doing. Doesn't mean it's not there, I just never encountered it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did this not work?

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), m.begin1());
```

this will occupy the first `v.size()` elements of `m` with the value of v.

The following code compiles and runs on my system (boost 1.48 and g++ 4.62)

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    boost::numeric::ublas::vector<int> v(10);
    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<int> m(10,10);  //using v.size() also works
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), m.begin1());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your matrix is 10 x 10. The point is to copy a vector of size  N to a matrix of size 1 x N.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you're trying to access 1st row which just isn't there for 1 x v,size() matrix. You should write:

```
ublas::matrix_row<ublas::matrix<double> > r( m, 0 );
```

though you'd be better with

```
row(m, 0) = v;
```